# Story where the word 'THOU' is used as a term of endearment

Tags: story-identification, robert-a-heinlein

I was sure that the term **THOU** was used in Heinlein's '*Time Enough for Love*', but I have not been able to find it within that book.

It was used by the main character as a short-hand term of endearment, something that they could say to each other to show that they are thinking of them, they love them, etc.

I think it might be from a Heinlein story.

Comment: The word "thou" is used a lot in Heinlein's *Stranger in a Strange Land*, mostly in the saying "Thou art God", but as in real life it's just a pronoun, not a "term of endearment". I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: I believe Piers Anthony, probably in one of the *Blue Adept* books, used "Thee, thee thee" as a declaration of love.

Comment: A search of the archive.org etext of Heinlein's *Time Enough for Love* finds only one instance of the pronoun "thou". It's in the Notebooks of Lazarus Long: "Thou shalt remember the Eleventh Commandment and keep it Wholly." Obviously not what you're looking for.

Comment: Why do you write "thou" in bold capitals? Was it printed that way in the book?

Comment: In general, "thou" as a pronoun is indeed supposed to be one indicating familiarity ("you" being the formal version that has since become ubiquitous). I believe the Society of Friends (nicknamed Quakers) still use it that way, as a term used among family and very close friends.

Comment: Was wondering if it could be Glory Road but I don't have a copy to hand and all the online quotes I can found do not include it ...

Comment: @FuzzyBoots -- some call that "plain speech". As I learned it (from Quaker family members), "thou" was not just for close friends, but for anyone -- in contradistinction to "you" as an unnecessary marker of status-based social separation, which runs counter to Quaker ideals that all are equal under God. "Thou" was later replaced by "thee" even in the nominative. That said, plain speech is generally confusing for anyone not accustomed to it, and I haven't encountered anyone using it in non-Quaker contexts. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testimony_of_simplicity#Simplicity_in_speech

Comment: Unrelated: Any chance you read [Buber's essay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_and_Thou)?

Comment: @AdamT The full text of *Glory Road* has been scanned into the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/isbn_0425028348/mode/2up?q=thou). You have to register (for free) if you want to borrow and read the book, but no registration is needed to search for words. The word "thou" occurs 7 times (not counting 3 hits for "thou-sand"), such as (p. 13) "I am not being holier-than-thou; I was after that same three-car garage myself." Not the book we're looking for. If it's really a Heinlein, I think *Stranger* is the most likely suspect.

Answer (score 21):

It's probably close enough to be worth an answer, but it's not Heinlein.  Piers Anthony has the inhabitants of Phaze use "thee, thee, thee" as a declaration of love in the [Apprentice Adept](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?580) series.  One of the first important times is in *Blue Adept* when Lady Blue declared her love for Stile.

Comment: I was going to bring this up also.  And, In the Magical land of Phaze, its the saying of "thee" 3 times it's like a binding spell between 2 people. (Similar to "I Do" when getting married)

Answer (score 18):

I wonder if you are (mis) remembering [Stranger in a Strange Land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stranger_in_a_Strange_Land) by Heinlein. In that book the phrase "Thou art God" is used a term of respect and/or endearment.

The term doesn't literally mean the person you are talking to is divine. It is the closest English gets to a concept from the Martian language:

> Mike remained in his trance; there was still much to grok, loose ends and bits and pieces to be puzzled over and fitted into his growing pattern - all that he had seen and heard and been at the Archangel Foster Tabernacle (not just the cusp he had encountered when he and Digby had come face to face alone), why Bishop Senator Boone had made him warily uneasy without frightening him, why Miss Dawn Ardent had tasted like a water brother when she was not, the texture and smell of the goodness he had incompletely grokked in the jumping up and down and the wailing - Jubal's stored conversation both coming and going - Jubal's words troubled him more than other details; he studied them with great care, compared them with what he had been taught as a nestling, making great effort to bridge between his two languages, the one he thought with and the one he now spoke and was gradually learning to think in, for some purposes.  The human word "church" which turned up over and over again among Jubal's words gave him most knotty difficulty; there was no Martian concept of any sort to match it - unless one took "church" and "worship" and "God" and "congregation" and many other words and equated them all to the totality of the only world he had known during most of his growing-waiting... then forced the concept back awkwardly into English in that phrase which had been rejected (but by each differently) by Jubal, by Mahmoud, by Digby.
>
> "Thou art God" He came closer to understanding it in English himself now, although it could never have the crystal inevitability of the Martian concept it stood for.  In his mind he spoke simultaneously the English sentence and the Martian word and felt closer grokking.  Repeating it like a student telling himself that the jewel is in the lotus he sank into nirvana untroubled.

Comment: Not Heinlein (or even science fiction at all) but "Thou" was very definitely used in James Clavell's Shogun in exactly the manner described between Blackthorne and his primary love interest Mariko.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir, it's been too long since I read that; is Clavell's use of "thou" intended as a translation of the way that Japanese pronouns have different degrees of intimacy?  Like modern _anata_ ("you", distant), _kimi_ ("you", casual / intimate), _omae_ ("you", very intimate, potentially insulting in the wrong contexts), etc. etc.?

Comment: @Eiríkr Útlendi : No, both Blackthorne and Mariko spoke Latin (in addition to other languages), in this case the use of "Thou" was the actual literal word used.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir Also, at the time Shogun is set, English was still using the t-v distinction, so use of "thou" would naturally indicate intimacy.

Comment: @user888379 : Except Mariko didn't know English, she initially shared Latin and Portuguese with Blackthorne, then Japanese after he learned that.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir To be honest, what I remember most about the book was Clavell's use of "flounder" when he meant "founder".